# Bootstrap Nested Table (Grid)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and I have a requirement to develop hierarchical grid with two levels; basically I need this kind of implementation with bootstrap table

http://www.trirand.net/aspnetmvc/grid/hierarchytwolevels

I search on the web and could not find any good resource with bootstrap hierarchical grid. Is there any possibility to implement hierarchical grid with bootstrap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have used html table, bootstrap and jquery datatable. here is the link how to develop nested datatable

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189621/Creating-an-expandable-master-details-table-jQuery

Comment: this link also discuss about the possible solution.      http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/1609/nested-tables